# Showing HTTP addresses as links

Tags: jsf, arraylist, hyperlink

I have a `List` of http addresses and I'd like to show them  as links, so that people could click and go to the website.

I'm trying to do it like this, but it shows the http address, but not as a link:

```
   Links Relacionados
      <br />
       <a4j:repeat value="#{pesquisaBean.selectedDocument.seeAlso}" var="uri" >

            <h:link value="#{uri}" outcome="#{uri}" />
             <br />
       </a4j:repeat>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: If they're external links, use `h:outputLink`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<h:link outcome>` takes either a JSF navigation case outcome,

```
<h:link ... outcome="nextpage" />
```

or a JSF view ID,

```
<h:link ... outcome="/nextpage.xhtml" />
```

but definitely not an external URL, it would render as a `<span>` instead of an `<a>`.

```
<h:link ... outcome="http://stackoverflow.com" /> <!-- Fail. -->
```

This failure should also have been logged in server log. At least, Mojarra does that with a JSF1090 warning. Look once again at your server log:

> WARNING: JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component j_idt7.

Use plain HTML `<a>` instead. You can specify the URL in its `href` attribute.

```
<a href="#{uri}">#{uri}</a>
```